# Android init.rc: unable to Create Symbolic Links

Tags: android, linux, init

I'm a beginner of Android.

I'm trying to make symlink by modifying init.rc file.
But when I insert below code, I see the result in adb shell. 
I can't find what I need.

```
symlink /data/.hidden /.hiddenlink
```

I had success generating /data/.hidden directory. But I failed to make hidden symbolic link to that directory.

I think there is no syntax error in the above command in init.rc file.
But I don't know why this happened.

Could you give me a solution?

Comment: did u get any solution for this?i am also facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try something like this

```
symlink /data/.hidden /.hidden
```

somehow some of the Android paths we need to give the same name for the soft link as that of the target file/folder name. It worked for me by doing this trick.